# For Loop Parsing with %

Tags: python, parsing

Just started learning Python a month ago.  I'm stumped on an issue.
Trying to update a dictionary using a for loop.  I would like to store the variable using the for loop's variable name as key and the variable value as the dictionary's value.  I'm trying to use % to make it a one liner.  Here's what I have so far:

```
grbl_parser_d = {
'a': 'null',  # Motion Mode
'b': 'null',  # Coordinate System Select
'c': 'null'  # Plane Select
}

grbl_out = [GC:G0 G54 G17]

def filtergrblparser():
    global grbl_parser_d
    for l, r in [grbl_out.strip('[]').split(':')]:
        for a, b, c in [r.split(' ')]:
            # grbl_parser_d.update({'%': x}) % x
            grbl_parser_d.update({'a': a})
            grbl_parser_d.update({'b': b})
            grbl_parser_d.update({'c': c})
```

The 'grbl_out' variable is the output from an Arduino.

Trying to use something like: grbl_parser_d.update({'%': a}) % a.name

'a.name' would be the for loop's variable name, not the value.  Is this even possible?  Any other suggestions and tips to clean up the code would also be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need loops for this, and I wouldn't try to cram it onto one line. Here's a simple function that should do what you want.

```
def filtergrblparser(grbl_out):
    l, r = grbl_out.strip('[]').split(':')
    a, b, c = r.split(' ')
    grbl_parser_d = {
        'a': a,  # Motion Mode
        'b': b,  # Coordinate System Select
        'c': c  # Plane Select
    }
    return grbl_parser_d

# I'm assuming you meant this to be a string
grbl_out = "[GC:G0 G54 G17]"

grbl_parser_d = filtergrblparser(grbl_out)

print(grbl_parser_d)
# {'a': 'G0', 'b': 'G54', 'c': 'G17'}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is generally a bad idea, but it *could* be done with another `for` loop.

```
# it's not clear why you're throwing this in a list just to iterate once over it
l, r = grbl_out.strip('[]').split(':')
a, b, c = r.split(' ')
for k in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    grbl_parser_d[k] = vars()[k]
```

But really it looks like you're trying to do:

```
grbl_parser_d = dict(zip('abc', grbl_out.strip('[]').split(':')[1].split(' ')))
```

Which is probably best written as:

```
l, r = grbl_out.strip('[]').split(':')
grbl_parser_d = dict(zip('abc', r.split(' ')))
```

Comment: Thank  you!  grbl_parser_d = dict(zip('abc', grbl_out.strip('[]').split(':')[1].split(' '))) is exactly what I was looking for.